# Asterisk AMI set DND ON and OFF programatically

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am trying to send an AMI command to asterisk and set the specific extension DND status on and off.

```
Action: DBPut
Family: DND
Key: SIP/xxx
Val: "YES"
```

When I use the command above I get response: success, but the extension is still normally receiving calls?

Answer (score 0):

1) turn dnd on via web interface

```
asterisk -rx "database show"
```

2) turn off

3) do same

4) compare.

5) compare with what your app do(likly you have additional / or something like that)

Comment: yes, it is for linux commandline to be executed via ssh on asterisk host. Use windows version of asterisk is REALLY REALLY bad idea.

Comment: But you also can issue ami command COMMAND and get same output via AMI (for check, not use in production).

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why is it a very bad idea to use the Windows version of Asterisk, I am intrigued.

Comment: Asterisk developed for linux. Linux asterisk have 50+ mlns installs/laste 10 years, windows version - maybe 1000 installs overal. Even asterisk on vmware(linux vm) under windows will work better then that buggy code which proposed as "asterisk for windows".